# How do i bind select box with input in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to bind select box with input so I have a select box with pre defined options and when selected that option will be in the input and when the user types text in the input a dynamic `new` select option should be made if it is not in the pre defined list else it should match on one of the items.

```
<div class="col-md-2 text-center">          
   <select class="form-control" v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="item in inventory" :value="item" :key="item.id">
      @{{ item.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <p>
    @{{ selected.id}}
  </p>            
</div>

<input v-model="inputBind" placeholder="," type="text" class="form-control">
```

and

```
 new Vue({
    el:'#app',
     data:{
       inputBind:'',
       inventory: [
          {name: 'MacBook Air', id: 1},
          {name: 'MacBook Pro', id: 2},
          {name: 'Lenovo W530', id: 3},
          {name: 'Acer Aspire One', id: 4}
        ],
        selected: 2
      },
     created: function() {
          this.selected = this.inventory.find(i => i.id === this.selected);
      },
```

Comment: When a user adds text in the input element, how should that be selected in the select? Do you mean that what they enter should be added as an option?

Comment: yes ! it should bind the input with select so the user will have 2 option one to get from select and one if he want custom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the the same data attr for the input, check [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Trekels/51r03zjc/) that way data is shared by both the inputs. Its is the easiest way. Note that for the select box to select the correct option now you must enter the matching value. Don't know what the reason is you need it this way but its not that user friendly.

Js

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    selected: 'item1',
    input: '',
    items: {
      1: {id: 1, val: 'item1'},
        2: {id: 2, val: 'item2'},
        3: {id: 3, val: 'item3'},
    }
  }
});
```

Html

```
<div id="app">

  <select class="form-control" v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="item in items" :value="item.val" :key="item.id">
     {{ item.val }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <p>
    {{ selected }}
  </p>

  <input v-model="selected" placeholder="," type="text" />

</div>
```

Comment: where do you bind input ?

Comment: @Adriankevin Input is bound on the same data attr `selected` so it shares the same value as the select box.

Comment: ok and if have put other attr from input to cars for example how do i bind i need to learn it :) normaly i bine with v-model i don't see it :)

Comment: loool now i see it you put selected sorry by bad :)

Comment: when i put in the input data who can i see the option in select the bind works but it don't show it.

Comment: @Adriankevin Sorry my bad forgot to fill in the value of the option, edited the Js fiddle to print the val in the option tag

Comment: can you modify it to show new option in selected when i put in input ?

Comment: It already does it ? if i type `option1` or `option2` in the input it changes the select box value. Or what do you mean?

Comment: if i put in input for example 'abc' in the select box and input is blank, maybye it needed to push new string in array select ?

Comment: try to put something to input to see, In the select box it don't apper it bind the value but it don't show there.

Comment: So you actually want the input to dynamicaly add a option if it does not exitst in the list else select an existing ?

Comment: yes :) add an option if not exist and select, If exitst put that one

Comment: @Adriankevin updated the fiddle, needs some refinement but roughly it works

Comment: Hello @Vincent T I want some help in select-option, can you please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647128/vuejs-how-to-display-any-string-passed-in-the-data-and-if-it-does-not-matches

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to `change` and which is fired after the model value has been updated like so:

```js
<select class="form-control" v-model="selected" @change="doSomethingWithChangedValue">
    <option v-for="item in inventory" :value="item" :key="item.id">
      @{{ item.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```